# Understanding PATH environment variables and different versions of Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line, environment-variables, path-variables

I am struggling to get "scrapy" recognised as a command from Windows 10 command prompt. I realised this is (likely) because the running Python version in the folder I am executing the command from is Python 3.9 64-bit, but my PATH environment variables for Python and Python scripts are both set for Python 3.8 32-bit.

So my question is, why/how does typing:

```
python --version
```

on the command line show me that the running version of Python is 3.9; how can the command line even recognise 'python' as a command and associate this with 3.9 when I have not added 3.9 to my PATH variables?
Does it automatically choose 3.9 because my laptop is 64-bit? And finally, can I add:

C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-64
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-64\Scripts\

to my PATH variables, alongside the existing:

C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\

Thank you!

Comment: I think in the installation time you might have checked the add python to environment variables and python 3.9 is being detected by your system. Secondly is there a need to keep python 3.8 and 3.9 in your system?

Comment: @dqureshiumar I can't think of a need to except for a (perhaps irrational) fear that any existing projects built using 3.8 will be affected if I delete it

Comment: No I dont think there might me any errors or bugs unless some projects are built on `python2`. If you want to change your python version to 3.8 or any you need to set your path to the respective folder. Finally you should use a single python either 3.8 or 3.9.

Comment: Run `where.exe python` to exhaustively search for all "python" commands in `PATH`. The first match is the one that normally gets executed.